# How to use the Active Life Mat with a Wii Mini?

Tags: controllers, nintendo-wii

I read that the Active Life Mat uses a physical Game Cube plug. Is there some solution for using the Active Life Mat with a Wii Mini?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Wii Mini is characterized by lacking any form of GC compatibility or online connectivity. If you want to use an accessory that requires backward compatibility, you'll need an original model Wii (the one with a stand).